# Basis of the orthogonal component

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be an orthogonal basis for $R^n$ and let $W=\operatorname{span}\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$. Is it necessarily true that $W^\perp=\operatorname{span}\{v_{k+1},\dots,v_n\}$? Either prove that it is true or find a counterexample.

I have the feeling that the statement is false, while I think that the span of $W^\perp$ could also consist of less vectors than $n$. However, I don't know whether I'm correct and how I could give a formal proof. Could anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **is** necessarily true. Let $v\in W^\perp$. Then $v=w+u$ for some $w\in W$ and $u\in \operatorname{span}\{v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n\}$. Since $w\in W$ and $v\in W^\perp$, we have $0=\langle v,w\rangle=\langle w+u,w\rangle=\|w\|^2$. Therefore $w=0$ and $v=u\in \operatorname{span}\{v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n\}$. That is, $W^\perp\subseteq\operatorname{span}\{v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n\}$. The inclusion in reverse direction is trivial.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)!!